# Getting the error message when running ' composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0" '

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php, require

When I run this command `composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"` I get these error messages:

> Problem 1
>
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP 
>     extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP 
>     extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb (locked at 1.5.1, required as 
>     ^1.5) -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.5.1].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
>
> - C:\PHP7\php.ini
>       You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP 
>     in CLI mode.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening as I am quite new to Php & composer ?

It looks like the `mongodb` extension is causing the issues. I dont need mongodb anymore and I deleted the `;extension=php_mongodb.dll` lines in my `Php.ini` files

Comment: You still have mongodb referenced in either your composer.json, or composer.lock. Double-check your composer.json, delete your composer.lock, and try again.

Comment: can you post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have `mongodb` referenced in either your `composer.json`, or `composer.lock`. Double-check your `composer.json`, delete your `composer.lock`, and then run your composer command again.